# M-. takes over my commands and can't execute OR C-g to escape

Tags: minibuffer, ctags, gtags, tags

I am using Emacs 26.3 and trying out `ggtags-company-mode` to navigate my code base.

I move my cursor to a function I want to jump to the definition of, `poll_count`, and enter `M-`.

I now have this at the bottom of my session in the minibuffer:

[image]

But when I try to tab to it (I have ido-everywhere), It inserts an actual tab:

[image]

So I hit backspace to remove the `TAB` and hit `RET`.  But now it inserts a literal `RET`:

[image]

I want to /select/ this not insert a literal enter.  So now I want to give up, and I type `C-g` to cancel this command in the minibuffer:

[image]

It says quit, but then comes right back to:

[image]

It does this no matter how many times I hammer `C-g C-g`. So now my editor is stuck here and this is my life now.  I can neither escape the command to terminate it with `C-g`, nor execute it with `TAB` or `RET`.

For what it's worth, the `poll_count` function is defined just a few lines above in the same file, so I didn't expect this to be such a trap.

### Update

`C-]` and `ESC ESC ESC` both cancel the command OK, so I am not trapped in the minibuffer forever, but I still can't seem to select the `Jump to:` target correctly.

Comment: Did you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, see if you get the same problem. And please cite your Emacs version/build.

Comment: Using Emacs 26.3

Comment: Put all relevant info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.